# Access user folders via Terminal

Tags: macos, security, terminal, sudo

When I am using Terminal to go to different folders such as Documents, Downloads, Photos etc I get presented with a dialog requesting me to grant Terminal access to these folders such as below:

[image]

Is there anyway to bypass this by using Sudo rights in Terminal such as:

```
$ sudo cd ~/Downloads
```

Unfortunately doing the above still shows the dialog when I was expecting the password to be enough. Is there any way to grant permission via terminal?

My OS is Catalina

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
System Preferences->
    Security & Privacy->
        Privacy tab->
            Full Disk Access->+Add [Applications -> Utilities -> Terminal]
```

Comment: Note that this is intentionally not automatable (except under certain circumstances) -- if it were possible to script this, malware authors would do this and bypass the protection, rendering it pointless. The point is to require specific **user** approval for applications (including Terminal) to access personal information.